# Problems with bootstrap grid not breaking or displaying properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stack, css-grid

I have run into a massive headache with boostrap errors on my page when it comes to the grid. I know I have done all that I can to figure out, and spent countless hours trying different things, all to no avail. I have the following code giving me problems. If you want to check out the site in action it is located here: [Sample Page](https://www.seneca-direct.com/index.php/products-test)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="prodStyles col-xs-12">
            <h2>ALL PRODUCT STYLES</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="prodImage">
            <img src="images/roll/king-blue.png" alt="cblue" class="alignnone" />
       </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="prodStyles">
            <ul>
                <li><span>KINGS</span></li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="prodImage">
            <img src="/images/roll/king-blue.png" alt="blue" class="alignnone" />
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="prodStyles">
            <ul>
                <li><span>KINGS</span></li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I was able to get it close, but it wasn't breaking where I wanted it to for small screens. I would like it to always be a minimum of 2 columns wide, and 4 columns wide for medium screens and above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only change you need to make is `col-md-6` to `col-md-3`.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
```

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is intentional or not, but your first column is currently wrapping around all the other columns. If not, just move its closing `</div>` tag up so its no longer surrounding the others.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap grid works in a way that there are 12 columns in a row. And you divide them however you want - for two columns you set two `div`s with `col-md-6` (for medium resolution, hence `md`). So, if you want to have 2 columns for small and extra small screens, 4 columns for medium screen, and let's say 6 columns for large screen, your code would look something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a closure div after first col element on second row. And have 1 extra div of closure outside. try this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="prodStyles col-xs-12">
        <h2>ALL PRODUCT STYLES</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="prodImage">
            <img src="images/roll/king-blue.png" alt="cblue" class="alignnone" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="prodStyles">
            <ul>
                <li><span>KINGS</span></li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="prodImage">
            <img src="/images/roll/king-blue.png" alt="blue" class="alignnone" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="prodStyles">
            <ul>
                <li><span>KINGS</span></li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```